# Adding new view to Window whilst in Landscape mode renders view in portrait mode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am using Xcode's SplitView template in Landscape mode.

In the AppDelegate I am adding a new view to the window whilst in Landscape mode however it appears in Portrait mode.

I want it to be added in Landscape mode over the splitview.

My plist is set to LandscapeLeft only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[self.splitViewController.view addSubview:newController.view];